# recreate core database

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

So I've Uploaded a binary to the app store a while back. Throughout some time The source got got a little missed up and I don't have the source database modal.

Is it possible to recreate the database modal? I know the fields and all of that and I have the hashes of the old modal however, it seems whenever I try to recreate the database modal the hashes do not match up.

Answer (score 0):

Well after alot of playing I got one of the hashes to match. Guess I just have to keep tweaking settings till they both match.